# Sphinx command line viewer

Tags: gratis, command-line, code-beautification

Is there any utilty similar to `cat`, but for Sphinx (reStructuredText) files? In the sense that, since some terminals now support bold, italics, and other such markup, is there a utility that "renders" Sphinx files in the terminal with these features?